# about transpose of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a real $n\times n$ matrix with $A^{T}=\alpha_{0}I+\alpha_{1}A$, where $\alpha_{0}$ and $\alpha_{1}$ are real numbers. Show that either $A^{T}=\pm A$ or $A=\lambda I$ for some real number $\lambda$.
Can someone give me hint?

Comment: What are the diagonal entries of $A-A^T$?

Answer (score 6):

The statement is not true. Consider $A=\pmatrix{2&-1\\ 1&2}$. Then $A^T=4I-A$ but $A^T\neq\pm A$ or $\lambda I$.

Answer (score 3):

We are given $A^t=aI+bA\dots(0)$(for simplicity I am writing $a,b$)

Taking transpose of the above equation we get $(A^t)^t=aI+bA^t \Rightarrow A=aI+b(aI+bA)$

Thus we have,

$(1-b^2)A=a(1+b)I\tag1$

if $(1-b^2)\ne0$ then we have $A=\frac{a(1+b)}{1-b^2}I=\lambda I$(here $\lambda=\frac{a(1+b)}{1-b^2}$)

and if $1-b^2=0$ then we have from $(1)$, $a(1+b)=0$

SO either $b=-1$ or $a=0$.

If $a=0$ then from $(0)$ we have $A^t= A$ as $(1-b^2)=0$ and $(1+b\ne 0)\Rightarrow b=1$

If $b=-1$ then we have $A^t=aI-A$

Note that the statement in the question is not correct for $\alpha_1\ne -1$.

Comment: or $b=-1$...have you read the other answer?

Comment: from (1), $a(1+b)=0$ so $a=0$ OR $b=-1$.

Comment: Yes I had made a mistake,which I have corrected now.

Comment: If $1-b^{2}=0$, then we can have $b=1,-1$. If $b=1$, then $a=0$, $A^{T}=A$. If $b=-1$, then $a$ can be any real number,then we also can get $A^{T}=-A$.

Comment: How ??? see ,for example ,the answer posted by user1551 below.

Comment: Could you tell us what is the problem of the proof above?

Comment: I think I have made it clear in my proof. Please tell me the part you dont understand in this proof. I will explain.

Comment: I think $\alpha_{1}$ can be $-1$. Please see the my comment above.